# Strange bug with OpenLayers + CloudMade

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, cloudmade

I am trying something fairly simple, you can see a demo here:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/VVe8x/19/

This bug only appears in Firefox, so to see it press either one of the links once (it will take you to either NY or Israel) then press the other link.
The bug is that it will not show me the tiles in that location, instead it will show me the background of the div.

P.S In Chrome this works flawlessly.

I dont know if this is a clue or it might confuse you, if in between pressing either NY or Israel links you press the "view the world" link it will allow you then to see the other location..

Full Source for reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <body>

    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:show1()">show me NY</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:show2()">show me TLV</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:map.zoomToExtent(map.getMaxExtent());">show world map(a "workaround"</a>


    <div id='myMap' style="height: 600px; width: 600px; position: relative"></div>

    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://developers.cloudmade.com/attachments/download/58/cloudmade.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("myMap", {
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()
            ]
        });

        var cloudmade = new OpenLayers.Layer.CloudMade("CloudMade", {
            key: 'd5da652e33e6486ba62fca3d18ba70c9'
        });
        map.addLayer(cloudmade);

        var epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(40, 32), 2);

        show1 = function(){
        var bound1 = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-8236567.917898,4972686.066032,-8236148.409989,4972889.624407);
            map.zoomToExtent(bound1); // to NY
        };

        show2 = function(e){
            var bound2 = new OpenLayers.Bounds(3874818.203389,3773932.267033,3875217.305962,3774226.370443);   
            map.zoomToExtent(bound2); // to Israel
            return false;
        };

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The myMap_OpenLayers_Container has the following CSS when the tiles are invisible:

position: absolute; z-index: 749; left: -2.02815e+7px; top: -2007340px;

If you change these around you can see that the correct tiles were loaded, so its likely to be jsFiddle messing them up. The tiles CSS when they don't show also have strange values.

**Update**:

Testing locally also produces the issue, so that rules out jsFiddle.

A fix would be to set this value after the zoom by calling a function such as:

```
        updateCSS = function(){
            OpenLayers_Container = document.getElementById("myMap_OpenLayers_Container").style.left = "0px";
        }
```

This looks like a bug, although if it is in OpenLayers or the CloudMade layer properties is hard to tell - I'd imagine the latter, or it would be a widely reported bug. The relevant code in OpenLayers.js appears to be:

```
centerLayerContainer: function(lonlat){
    var originPx = this.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(this.layerContainerOrigin);
    var newPx = this.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(lonlat);
    if ((originPx != null) && (newPx != null)) {
        this.layerContainerDiv.style.left = Math.round(originPx.x - newPx.x) + "px";
        this.layerContainerDiv.style.top = Math.round(originPx.y - newPx.y) + "px";
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this is not a bug with jsFiddle, I had this issue in my dev environment and I replicated it in jsFiddle.
The css is a nice find, I will look into it when I have time, need to figure out who is generating this error..

Again, jsFiddle is not to blame here :)
I dont make a habit developing on top of jsFiddle :P

Comment: Yup, I can see the bug with the view port DIV, I will use your workaround!

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this problem too, and it turned out I was not setting the map's center as I thought I was. The problem goes away if you first call map.setCenter(). For example:

```
var newCenter = new OpenLayers.Lonlat(longitude, latitude)
    .transform(new OpenLayers.Projection('ESPG:4326'),
               this.map.getProjectionObject());

this.map.setCenter(newCenter);
```

Hope this helps whoever next has the problem.